# How to I make a list of tibbles?

Tags: r, tibble

I have a function that returns a tibble/dataframe. I need to run it several times and put the results into one large tibble. But everything I've tried throws an error or breaks the tibble down into a simple vector.

```r
tibbles = list()

for (i in 1:10) {
  # call a function that returns a tibble
  mytibble = tibble(x=rnorm(10), y=sample(LETTERS, 10), z=i)
  # add to list
  tibbles[i] = mytibble
}
# make one big tibble
data = bind_rows(tibbles)
```

Result:

```
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Use `[[` to access or assign to a single element of a `list`. If you changes `tibbles[i] = mytibble` to `tibbles[[i]] = mytibble`, I think your code will work.

Comment: Thank you! Double brackets tricks me every time.